# C++ pointer isn't working

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc

I have this function that asigns a values

```
void asignaMatrizCostos(int n){
   int i, j;
   if (n == 4){
      for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
          for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
             *(GLOBAL_mC++) = (i == j ? 0.0 : (double)(10 * i) + j);
          }
      }
  }
```

And another function to print it

```
void imprimeCostos(int n){
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         cout << ' ' << (*GLOBAL_mC++);
         cout << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

And here's my main

```
int main_ciclos(int argc, char** argv){
   int n = 4;
   GLOBAL_mC = (double*) malloc( n * n * sizeof(double));

   asignaMatrizCostos(n);
   int p[] = {3,1,2,0};
   double res = 0; // costo(p, n);

   imprimeCostos(n);
}
```

But in the output I get this

[image]

It should be a 2D array with doubles

Comment: `GLOBAL_mC` just keeps increasing in value. How is it supposed to print out the same information you put into it when you never set it back to its starting position?

Comment: This looks like C code (except for I/O). In genuine  C++ you'll use [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) or at least `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GLOBAL_mC = (double*) malloc( n * n * sizeof(double));
doSomethingWith(GLOBAL_mC++);
```

You need to think about what `GLOBAL_mC` is set to after those two statements, that's basically what you're doing in your code.

A hint: it's *not* the start of the array any more.

---

What you need to do is modify your code so that it *doesn't* change the variable at all. For example, that could be done with something like:

```
void asignaMatrizCostos(int n) {
    double *ptr = GLOBAL_mC;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            *(ptr++) = (i == j) ? 0.0 : 10.0 * i + j;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice I've also fixed your problem with using indexes `1..n` rather than `0..(n-1)`. You may have to adjust the values loaded into the matrix depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank's it worked! Do you know what happens if i don't put free() when it's finished? When does that block of memory gets availabe again?

Comment: If you don't free it the memory will remain allocated until execution is finished...memory leak

Comment: @Pepe, if that was really main, it wouldn't matter since the memory would almost certainly be released with the process. The fact that it's `main_ciclos` means that you *could* be subject to a serious memory leak depending on how often it's called.